# Why $\|u\|_{\tau}\leq C[u]_{W^{s,p}}^a\|u\|_{L^q}^{1-a}$ not correct for $p=1$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In an article I have the following lemma :

> Let $d\geq 1$, $p>1$, $q\geq 1$, $\tau>0$, $s\in(0,1)$ and $a\in(0,1]$ s.t. $$\frac{1}{\tau}=a\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{s}{d}\right)+\frac{1-a}{q}.$$
>
> Then $$\|u\|_{L^\tau(\mathbb R^d)}\leq C[u]_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb R^d)}^a\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^d)}^{1-a},\quad u\in \mathcal C^1_0(\mathbb R^d),$$
> for some positive constant independent of $u$.

I recall that $\mathcal C^1_0(\mathbb R^d)$ is the space of $\mathcal C^1$ function over $\mathbb R^d$ that are compactly supported and that $$[u]_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb R^d)}^p=\iint_{\mathbb R^{2d}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}}dxdy.$$

My question is : why doesn't it work for $p=1$ ? I let you the proof below. [image]

Comment: This proof looks like taken from some book.What book?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz :  thank you for your interest. Unfortunately there is no book ! I wrote it. The article is : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123617302732?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with $p = 1$ is that some definitions of fractional Sobolev spaces  that were equivalent when $p > 1$ (by the Gagliardo seminorm that you gave, by interpolation between functional spaces, by trace theory, by harmonic analysis (Littlewood-Paley decomeposition)) are not anymore equivalent when $p = 1$.

So, one should be careful about the case $p=1$ and check whether the Sobolev inequality holds for that definition.

With the Gagliardo seminorm as in the question, the Sobolev inequality holds (see for example [*Augusto C. Ponce, Elliptic PDEs, measures and capacities. From the Poisson equation to nonlinear Thomas-Fermi problems, EMS Tracts in Mathematics 23. Zürich: European Mathematical Society (EMS) (2016)*](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/140), Proposition 15.5 and thus the lemma also holds for $p = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So if I understand well, this lemma can not hold for an other Gagliardo semi-norm, right ? Do you have such example ?

Comment: I am stating that it is holding for the Gagliardo seminorm, that when $p = 1$ the Gagliardo seminorm is not anymore equivalent to other quantities that are equivalent when $p > 1$. I think that the lemma should hold for several other norms, but this should be proved on a case by case basis.

Comment: I'm very satisfied by your answer. Could you may be give my just two gagliardo semi norm that are not equivalent when $p=1$ ?